# How to put a AdMob banner below a view with MATCH_PARENT height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

I have a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTitleStrip` which has `MATCH_PARENT` height. The pages has only some text, but some pages have vertical scroll because the text is very long.

Now I'm trying to find the best strategy to put an AdMob banner in the bottom of my layout. This is the situation:

- If I put below the `ViewPager`, the banner is not visible, because the `ViewPager` has `MATCH_PARENT`.
- If I put in the bottom of the layout, then, the `ViewPager` is scrolling content from behind the banner, and this is not a correct behaviour.

It is possible to put a rule which makes the banner to stay below the `ViewPager` but without making scrolling content of the `ViewPager` to be from behind the banner?

The way I'm trying to add the banner:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adsParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.pager);
        if (AdManager.getInstance().getAdView()!=null){
            View view = AdManager.getInstance().getAdView();
            mainLayout.addView(view, adsParams);
        }
```

My layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                style="@style/CustomPagerTitleStrip"/>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        style="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap the `ViewPager` and the banner in a layout, say `LinearLayout`, and stack them on top of each other? That way you won't have any content overlapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your layout XML res file add this attribute [android:layout_above](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_above) in MATCH_PARENT view. and in its value give the id of ad banner. Now your match_parent view will be above ad banner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why works if i put above and does not work if i put below on the banner view? it is confusing

Comment: Layout_above mean this match_parent view should be above specified ad banner view.

Comment: Yes, but layout_below is the inverse, and should work if i put on the banner view, which is the view that must be below the other. Dont work. Why?

Comment: No it won't work as MATCH_PARENT mean this view should fill whole parent screen and when you put adbanner as layout_below it will be below device screen. so it wont show up

Comment: You can actually see all possible position in preview window or design tab of xml layout files in android studio

Comment: Nope it is actually inverse, but you have to be sure that the view on top must not fill whole screen